# How to make CodeDeploy Blue/Green create CloudWatch alarms for custom metrics?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I am using the CloudWatch agent to create metrics for disk usage, memory usage, cpu, and a couple other things. I would like to aggregate metrics based on the autoscaling group, using `"AutoScalingGroupName":"${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}"`.

However, I'm using Blue/Green deployments with CodeDeploy, which creates a copy of the Autoscaling Group. The alarms I originally made for aggregations on the autoscaling groups are gone, and I can't put a widget in my Dashboard that shows avg cpu, memory, etc.

My quick solution was to use a custom `append_dimension` that is set to a hardcoded value, and aggregate dimensions on that. Is there an automated way that AWS provides that I don't know about?

Comment: append_dimensions is the only way I can think as well. Even with other with other metric platforms like InfluxDB/Telegraf, you'd have to specify some custom tag, like service/tier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience of the above scenario using AWS console.

But, since I work on Terraform (infrastructure as code) mostly, you can use like this:

```
dimensions = {
    AutoScalingGroupName = tolist(aws_codedeploy_deployment_group.autoScalingGroup.autoscaling_groups)[0]
  }
```

Reason for converting it into list - the output of

> aws_codedeploy_deployment_group.asg.autoscaling_groups

is a set value, which you can see when you output the value of the codedeployment group autoscaling group - it uses `toset` function. The metric dimensions for the CloudWatch metric alarm expects a `string`. So, the conversion of a `set` type (which is unordered) to `list` type is needed so that you can access the first element of the autoscaling group - which is the newly created copy of the autoscaling group by codedeploy.